# Spring MVC - Set an actionURL parameter with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, spring-mvc, portlet

Is it possible to dynamically set a Spring MVC portlet:actionURL portlet:param using javascript?  I have tried with the following code, but the id value always comes across as null to the controller. I have verified that setting the portlet:param manually passes the value correctly:

```
<portlet:param name="id" value="2" />
```

I have also verified the value in the javascript is being set correctly and is not null.

**(Note: I've changed the variable names, etc. from the original code to simplify it and obfuscate it since it is my employer's code.)**

JSP:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="modifyURL">
    <portlet:param name="do" value="modify" />
    <portlet:param name="id" value="${model.id}" />
</portlet:actionURL>

...

<form:form action="${modifyURL}" id="modifyForm" modelAttribute="model">
    <form:hidden path="id" id="id" />
</form:form>
```

Javascript called when the update URL is clicked:

```
function update() {
    document.forms[0]["id"].value = selectedId;
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(params = {"do=modify"})
public void modify(@ModelAttribute("model") Model model, 
    @RequestParam(value = "id", required=true) Long id,
    ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response,
    SessionStatus sessionStatus, ModelMap modelMap)  {
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker figured it out.  It looks like you just have to add the parameter to the action within the javascript and not include it in the actionURL or form.

JSP:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="modifyURL">
    <portlet:param name="do" value="modify" />
</portlet:actionURL>

...

<form:form action="${modifyURL}" id="modifyForm" modelAttribute="model" method="POST">
</form:form>
```

Javascript called when the update URL is clicked:

```
function update() {
    $("modifyForm").action = '${modifyURL}&id='+selectedId;
    $("modifyForm").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this almost 3 years later, still i found it easier to add  a hidden form field and when the action is clicked than to set this value to the hidden field

something like

```
 <input type="submit" id="btn_terminate_cmpn"
                value="Terminar campa&ntilde;a" onclick="setAction('terminate');">
```

and the javascript code

```
function setAction(action){
    $("#actionToDo").val(action);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL generated by the portlet tag is on the server side.  Javascript doesn't see the portlet tag.  It only sees the actual URL. What your coworker is suggesting would work but it's not a good approach.  Here he's just adding the dynamic parameter as a query string parameter which makes it visible to all the portlets on your target portal page.  A better solution is to keep a hidden element (text box or something) and set the dynamic value to this hidden element in your onSubmit Javascript hander function.